# oracle reentrant alter table

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, reentrancy

I have an SQL script to execute multiple times (must be reentrant).

One of the script line is

```
alter table MATABLE modify (MADATA null);
```

This commands works well when the 'not null' constraint for column MADATA of table MATABLE is effectively removed. But the second time, I got an error, example:

```
Erreur SQL : ORA-01451: colonne à modifier en non renseignée (NULL) ne peut être passée à NULL
01451. 00000 -  "column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL"
```

That's because the constraint was already removed by the first execution and no more exist.

How to execute this same script without error ? 
maybe through PL/SQL Script ?

Comment: I don't know enough about oracle to tell you how to do it, but I assume you can check the structure of the table and only execute this part of the script if the columns is not nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data dictionary view `user_tab_cols` to check the table before doing the update.

```
declare
    lCount number;
begin

    select count(*) into lCount from user_tab_cols
    where table_name = 'MATABLE'
    and column_name = 'MADATA'
    and nullable = 'N';

    if (lCount = 1) then
        execute immediate 'alter table MATABLE modify (MADATA null)';
    end if;

end;
```

Note that `user_tab_cols` only contains the information about tables in the same schema as the logged on user. If you are modifying tables of another user, you can user `all_tab_cols` or `dba_tab_cols`.

Another option would be to use an exception handler and just throw away the exception, like this:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'alter table MATABLE modify (MADATA null)';
exception
    when others then
        null;
end;
```

Comment: PERFECT answer. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @boly38 I changed the answer, but note that both views `user_tab_cols` and `user_tab_columns` would work for you.

Comment: in fact the issue is the following: (just replace "into" by "as" for lCount definition).

Comment: Using `as` in place of `into` would result in an exception. `as` is used to give an alias to a column. `into` is used to save the value of an column to a local variable. Therefore in this case, `into` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior.

It can happen in two scenarios :

**1) If your field column is a constraint**

**2) if you've already defined the field column as allowing NULL values.**

Comment: Understood that point, I would like a workaround like @Thomas Tschernich answer. Thanks anyway